How to save and restore cursor position?
After performing some operations on cells in a notebook (with NotebookWrite and NotebookDelete) I need to restore the cursor's position within a particular cell. How can this be done?
I've found that Developer`CellInformation[obj] gives the cursor location information to save, but I don't know how to set that back after the operations are complete.

Have you tried MoveMouse?

@Domen Ah that is a nice function, however the notebook operations performed will likely move the target initial/final cell vertically so I don't think this would solve it.
